# RecyclerView with SQlite

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop

I am having a little difficulty in insert data from SQLite to RecyclerView. You have a way to handle this error? 
[image: source code 1]

Function get ALl Data and insert data, Now Data is Null because I want to insert data in database from screen user.

[image: source code 2]

Comment: this is error: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList mydialog.vuductri.ex3list.databaseManager.DatabaseUtil.getAllPhim()' on a null object reference " "at mydialog.vuductri.ex3list.MainActivity.prepareData(MainActivity.java:62)
                                                                               at mydialog.vuductri.ex3list.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)"

Comment: Please note that [comments are temporary and could be deleted anytime](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have additional information to provide, such as the error log, please update your question by clicking on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is `db`?

Assuming it is a class, I think the error is because you haven't initialize `db` object, yet you tried to use it.

`db = new SomeClass();`